# Getting 'mavenJava' cannot be applied to warning

Tags: java, gradle, java-17

I am using java17 and gradle version 7.6. In Intellij my below gradle file gives **'mavenJava' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Class<org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication>, groovy.lang.Closure<org.gradle.api.publish.Publication>)'** warning.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.sonarqube'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

mainClassName = "com.fasttrack.codegenerator.CodeGenerator"

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.6.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.15.1'
    implementation 'velocity:velocity-dep:1.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.0'
    implementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.0'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'repos'
        }
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.host.url", "http://sonarqube.fasttrack.local")
        property("sonar.sources", "src/main/java/")
        property("sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco")
        property("sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec")
    }
}
```

I tried to compile my project using gradle sync in build.gradle but got the above mentione warning in intellij. Please give me solution for this and what could be the reason

[Screenshot of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjyeF.png)